# INNER JOIN error: #1054 - Unknown column 'users.address_id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

As the error says: I think something is wrong about my query.. this is my table setup in MySQL:

Users:
id - username - password - salt surname - name - joined - email_id - permissions_id - address_id - address_2_id

Emails: 
id - email - subscriber

Addresses:
id - street - street_number - zip_code - city - country - phone - btw_number - company

And this is the query I wanted to use:

```
SELECT 
    users.id,
    users.username,
    users.password,
    users.salt,
    users.surname,
    users.name,
    users.joined,
    users.email_id,
    users.permissions_id,
    users.address_id,
    users.address_2_id,

    emails.id,
    emails.email,
    emails.subscriber,

    a1.id AS a1_id,
    a1.street AS a1_street,
    a1.street_number AS a1_street_number,
    a1.zip_code AS a1_zip_code,
    a1.city AS a1_city,
    a1.country AS a1_country,
    a1.phone AS a1_phone,
    a1.btw_number AS a1_btw_number,
    a1.company AS a1_company,

    a2.id AS a2_id,
    a2.street AS a2_street,
    a2.street_number AS a2_street_number,
    a2.zip_code AS a2_zip_code,
    a2.city AS a2_city,
    a2.country AS a2_country,
    a2.phone AS a2_phone,
    a2.btw_number AS a2_btw_number,
    a2.company AS a2_company

FROM users, emails
INNER JOIN addresses AS a1 ON a1.id = users.address_id
INNER JOIN addresses AS a2 ON a2.id = users.address_2_id
WHERE users.username = 'araguera' AND users.email_id = emails.id
```

Does anybody spot my mistake?

Comment: Please don't mix implicit and explicit `join` syntax...  the implicit style was deprecated over 25 years ago.  As a simple rule, you should *never* have a comma in the `from` clause...

Comment: So how would you edit my query?

Comment: `users, emails` and `AND users.email_id = emails.id` should be `users inner join emails on users.email_id = emails.id`

Comment: `From users u Join emails e On e.Id = u.email_id Join ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `FROM` clause to this:

```
FROM users 
INNER JOIN emails ON users.email_id = emails.id
INNER JOIN addresses a1 ON a1.id = users.address_id
INNER JOIN addresses a2 ON a2.id = users.address_2_id
WHERE users.username = 'araguera'
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the table not having the `address_id` column, I can only think on a mix up of the implicit and explicit joins that you are using:

```
SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.username,
    u.password,
    u.salt,
    u.surname,
    u.name,
    u.joined,
    u.email_id,
    u.permissions_id,
    u.address_id,
    u.address_2_id,

    e.id,
    e.email,
    e.subscriber,

    a1.id AS a1_id,
    a1.street AS a1_street,
    a1.street_number AS a1_street_number,
    a1.zip_code AS a1_zip_code,
    a1.city AS a1_city,
    a1.country AS a1_country,
    a1.phone AS a1_phone,
    a1.btw_number AS a1_btw_number,
    a1.company AS a1_company,

    a2.id AS a2_id,
    a2.street AS a2_street,
    a2.street_number AS a2_street_number,
    a2.zip_code AS a2_zip_code,
    a2.city AS a2_city,
    a2.country AS a2_country,
    a2.phone AS a2_phone,
    a2.btw_number AS a2_btw_number,
    a2.company AS a2_company

FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN emails AS e
    ON u.email_id = e.id
INNER JOIN addresses AS a1 
    ON a1.id = users.address_id
INNER JOIN addresses AS a2 
    ON a2.id = users.address_2_id
WHERE u.username = 'araguera'
```